# C# trying to update a progress bar in WPF from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, progress-bar

I have a main window where i would like to update a progress bar from another class. For some reason I get the exception:

> Error CS1061  'Window' does not contain a definition for
>   'UpdateProgressBar' and no extension method 'UpdateProgressBar'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Window' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

Window:MainWindow

```
>   public void UpdateProgressBar(int input)
>         {
>             pBar.Value = input;
> 
>         }

 private void btnSaveFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TaskManager.ReadDBWriteFile));
        newThread.Start();
        while(TaskManager.load<=TaskManager.loadMax)
        {
            TaskManager.stuff(this);
        }

    }
```

Class where my progressbar is set:

```
   public void stuff(System.Windows.Window a)
        {

            int up = load;
            a.UpdateProgressBar(up);

        }
```

It seems like i make a mistake when i try to reference my MainWindows with  System.Windows.Window a, but i can not get it right. Maybe you can help.

Comment: your function "stuff" should have a MainWindow typed parameter, not a Window

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `UpdateProgressBar` is a method of `MainWindow` class, not `System.Windows.Window`.

And even if `MainWindow` inherits from `Window`, the parent class doesn't know about its inherithing types specific methods !

So the argument (if you can) of `stuff` should be `MainWindow a`. Or maybe your code should be reorganized, but it's hard to say with the code you give...

Comment: I changed my reference to MainWindow a. But now i get the error  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TaskManager.stuff(MainWindow)'  when i call stuff(this)

Comment: Well, and ? Is it any better ?

Comment: That's why I wrote that your code should probably be rewritten... but can't help with the sample of code you gave.

Comment: Well my goal is to set a progressbar value from another class, i thought this can't be so harde but i guess im wrong lol.

Comment: Well, you just need a ref to your instance of MainWindow in your "other class", at least.

Comment: This is actually the whole class. maximum and minimum are static values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102705/discussion-between-derbenutzer-and-raphael-althaus).

Comment: What about calling stuff() without paremeters and just throw an event so the mainwindow can bind to the updateprogress(int)?